# jquery - Bind datepicker event

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this code:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
```

And I am trying to bind it to input text that will appear later on.

```
$(".table tbody").prepend("<tr><td><input type='text' name='Date' value='' class='datepicker' /></td></tr>");
```

How would I do that?

Comment: You can't.  The selector is only going to find elements in the DOM at that point it time that it runs.  If you are going to insert new datepicker elements later, you need to initialize them when they are added

Comment: So would I call `$('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });` after I prepend my table?

Comment: Yes with a slight twist.  Once second, making an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the new datepicker, you have to initialize it.

```
var $newDatePicker = $("<tr><td><input type='text' name='Date' value='' class='datepicker' /></td></tr>");
$(".table tbody").prepend($newDatePicker);
$newDatePicker.find('.datepicker').datepicker(...);
```

Storing the new element in a variable will let you initialize only the new one you added, without having to try to find in the DOM which one is new, vs the ones that are already initialized.